# Define foreach step dynamically by arithmetic computations

Tags: foreach

Consider the following:

```
\newcommand{\numA}{4}
\foreach \j in {\numA,8,...,50}{...}
```

As expected, `\j` will be `4,8,12,...` and so on.

Now, my question is: how to automatically set the second value as `2*\numA`? I tried `{\numA,2*\numA,...,50}` but it does not work. Maybe I have to define a new command?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\numA}{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \j in {\numA,8,...,50}{
\node at (\j,0){\j};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\inteval{2*\numA}` supplied by [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp); it's incorporated in the latest LaTeX kernel, so doesn't need to be loaded explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numA}{4}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \j in {\numA,\inteval{2*\numA},...,50}{%
    \node at (\j,0){\j};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TIL, thanks. Where can we find the list of such commands available?

Comment: @mas: You can read the [`xfp` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/xfp).

Comment: Oh, very simple and easy solution. Thanks a lot.